# I can only install drivers in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, drivers, virus, anti-virus, safe-mode

Recently, I've ran into a problem regarding the Hamachi network driver which just wouldn't install. I thought it was a hamachi specific problem but turns out I can't install any other driver either, I've tried updating my video drivers, sound card drivers and network adapter drivers, all of which fails, but the older drivers were removed. I had to boot into safe mode in order to be able to install these drivers.

Maybe it's some kind of virus? I don't have the option to format this PC, because my windows 7 instalation disc is miles away and this internet connection is too slow.

Comment: Its entirely possible its a virus.  Have you verified the intrigity of your system image?  **Its very likely you will need that disk to solve this problem.**  Any solution to this problem requires that disk

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps in this post to verify your system is clean. - [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/100360/97028)

It may be a good idea to run [SFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) (system file checker) to verify the integrity of Windows files.

After all that, try installing the drivers by launching them from the context menu (right click) with `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: After trying everything I could possibly think of to fix this problem, I gave up and went the format/re-install windows 7 route. Someone brought my disc :]

Comment: For clarification, did you try the suggestions in this answer before formatting?

Comment: Yes I did, I ran a couple of anti-malware/rootkit tools and my avira antivirus which found and removed some infected files. This system file checker didn't find anything missing or whatever. The problem persisted